# Protractor: Not moving to the next piece of Code

Tags: typescript, protractor

"Else" code inside the "IsPresent()" doesnt get executed. Only "IF" code gets execute. Any reason why it is happening. I am using protractor with jasmine framework. In the Output, first the code executes "If" inside the "IsPresent()" function and then calling again the recursion, I expect that "else" block should be executed as per the value I am feeding from the excel. But the execution stops there and when I close the browser manually then it prints the statement inside the "else" of the "IsPresent()". Not able to identify why it got stuck and doesnt move. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Note: Have used recursion so that I can read values from excel file and print the output as per the index.

Below is the code I am using:

```
import { browser, protractor, element, by, By, ElementArrayFinder, ElementFinder } from "protractor";
import { Workbook } from "exceljs";
import { exists } from "fs";


describe('Search PID', () => {
    var Excel = require('exceljs');
    var wrkbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    wrkbook.xlsx.readFile("Path to the excel file");

    beforeAll(() => {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('My App URL');

    });

    function PIDMatching(value, index) {
        element(By.css('text[transform="translate(800.8947256481425,612.9323227754049)rotate(0)"]'))
                    .getText().then(function (PID) {
            console.log("PID is: " +PID);
            if (PID!=value)  {
                console.log("Unmatched PID is: " + value + " and counter is: " + index);
                element(By.css('a:nth-child(2) > div > img')).click();
                element(By.css('div.col-md-10 > input')).sendKeys(value);
                browser.sleep(2000);
                element(By.css('div.col-md-2 > button')).click();
                browser.sleep(5000);
                element(By.css('text[transform="translate(800.8947256481425,612.9323227754049)rotate(0)"]'))
                        .getText().then(function (PID) {

                    if (PID!=value) {
                        console.log("Unmatched PID in 2nd attempt is: " + 
                            value + " and counter is: " + index);
                    } else {
                        console.log("matched for PID  in 2nd time: " +
                            value + " and counter is: " + index);
                    }
                });
            } else if (PID==value) { 
                console.log("matched for PID at first attempt: " +
                    value + " and counter is: " + index) 
            }
        });
    }




    fit('Navigation', () => {
        var userNameField = element(By.id('mat-input-0'));
        var userPassField = element(By.id('mat-input-1'));
        var userLoginBtn = element(By.xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-side-menu/mat-card-actions/button'));
        userNameField.sendKeys('username');
        userPassField.sendKeys('pwd');
        userLoginBtn.click();
        browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('#assetsId > rect')), { x: 214.211, y: 69.6306 }).doubleClick().perform();
        browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('#assetsId > rect')), { x: 263.353, y: 177.73 }).doubleClick().perform();
        element(By.xpath('/html/body/a/div[2]/img')).click();
        browser.sleep(3000);
        element(By.css('li:nth-child(5) > a > div')).click().then(function () {
            // Click on Search icon
            var worksheet = wrkbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
            var rows = worksheet.rowCount;

            var loop = function(i) {
                if (i >= 1) {
                    var a = worksheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).value;  
                    element(By.css('a:nth-child(2) > div > img')).click();
                    element(By.css('div.col-md-10 > input')).sendKeys(a);
                    browser.sleep(2000);
                    element(By.css('div.col-md-2 > button')).click()
                    element(by.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"mat-dialog")]/app-error-dialog/div/div[1]/div/span'))
                        .isPresent().then(function (isVisible){   
                    console.log("count Value is: " +isVisible) ;   
                    if (isVisible == true) {
                        console.log("its present: ");
                        element(By.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"mat-dialog")]/app-error-dialog/div/div[1]/div/span')).click();
                        loop(i - 1);
                    } else {
                        console.log("its not present: ") ; 
                        PIDMatching(a, i);
                    }
                });
                element(By.css('li:nth-child(5) > a > div'))
                        .click().then(function () {
                    loop(i-1);
                });
            }
    }
    loop(rows);  

});
browser.close();
});
});
```

Comment: I downvoted because "urgent", not formatted code, not clear description.

Comment: Avoid using words like "urgent, help and please". This site is for helping by definition. To make "helping" easier and faster, invest in a clear description of the problem and minimize code to what's relevant and necessary. Thanks

Comment: After changes it can not work - work on curly brackets.

Comment: Now its fine?. I wonder are we solving problems on formatting or really focusing on actual problem.

Comment: Why you define `a` variable - you don't use it anywhere. From what you get `rows` value? Is it dependent of number of elements on the page? If yes - maybe you might use some methods available for `ElementArrayFinder`? See the doc: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder

Comment: Could you describe the purpose of the recursion as opposed to your attempted implementation? It appears you are clicking on the same buttons in each loop and seeing how many elements are being generated containing the id 'mat-dialog' but the last click I cannot understand? There are no returns so the two recursive loop calls will always be called

Comment: I agree here with @DublinDev. There's something that is not clear on why you need recursion.

Comment: So I made a stab at formatting your code. Its aligned weird so i can't follow. I tried to make some sense of it here but having "}" align vertically makes it tough to read. I also want more clarification for the need to do recursion and how you plan to await your recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Initial attempt: use async / await (still needs more info from author)

I would suggest using async / await since it will clean up your promises and chained then statements. In the above code, there were promises that were not chained with a `.then`. Using async / await should clean some of this up.

So for the initial pass please fix to use async / await. There's something going on with your recursion and I am not sure how to fix it based on what is provided (discussion in comments below).

Another reason why you need to do async / await is that Protractor will no longer support the control flow in the near future. To turn off the control flow (use async / await), you'll need to set `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in your Protractor configuration file.

```
// Please be consistent with your import of by. If you are using "By"
// then do not also use "by".

export async function loop(i: number): Promise<void> {

  if (i >= 1) {
    // This is not locating a web element by css. You should just use a
    // css selector. This can lead to brittle tests.
    await element(by.css('body > app-root > app-side-menu > mat-sidenav-container > mat-sidenav > mat-nav-list > div > div > div.col-md-2 > button')).click();

    // Same issue here. Documented at http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide
    const count = await element.all(by.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"mat-dialog")]/app-error-dialog/div/div[1]/div/span')).count();
    console.log(`count Value is: ${count}`);

    if (count <= 0) {
      const PID = await element(by.css('text[transform="translate(800.8947256481425,612.9323227754049)rotate(0)"]')).getText();
      console.log("PID is: " + PID);
    } else {
      await element(by.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"mat-dialog")]/app-error-dialog/div/div[1]/div/span')).click();
      await loop(i - 1);
    }

    // Not exactly sure what's going on here, I'm guessing you keep clicking
    // at the same transform and the count keeps decreasing. When the i - 1 = 0,
    // then break the recursion. Let's say in the first recursion, we i = 4.
    // We print out all the PIDs and then when i = 1, we will click the link,
    // then loop(0) and whatever loop(rows) is. After that, i = 2, we'll then
    // again do loop(1) and whatever loops(rows) is.
    //
    // Something isn't right here. I would maybe discuss what you are doing
    // html requires recursion.
    await element(By.css('body > app-root > app-side-menu > mat-sidenav-container > mat-sidenav-content > app-process-view-container > div > app-process-pane > div > mat-card > nav > div > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a > div')).click();

    // Much recursion. Such loops.
    await loop(i - 1);

    // rows = ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    await loop(rows);
  }
}
```

Please revise your question so we can understand the recursion part. What are you clicking? What should your test actually do. Please provide more info.

Comment: Have updated the question and also posted my whole piece of code for better visibility. Let me know if you have question regarding what & why i m using.